# How do I use custom functions after the dplyr %>% operator?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use a custom function with dplyr, so I don't have to repeat the following code several times.

Sample data:

```
print(df)

   Tran_Date         Account   Tran_Type    Fee
1 2011-07-14 32-90-014846-00        <NA> 444.15
2 2011-09-01 32-90-014846-00        <NA> 117.79
3 2011-11-10 32-90-015611-00        <NA> 534.45
4 2012-01-12    90-015926-00 court costs 450.00
5 2012-02-09    90-015821-00        <NA> 640.25
6 2012-02-09    90-015128-00        <NA>  90.00
```

Here is the custom function:

```
State <- function(x, y){
  mutate(`Account` = str_remove_all(`Account`, "-"),
      Account = case_when(
      startsWith(`Account`, y) ~ str_c(str_c("WC", x), `Policy #`),
      startsWith(`Account`, x) ~ str_c("WC", `Policy #`)
    ))
}

df %>% State(32, 90)

Error in State(., x = 32, y = 90) : unused argument (.)
```

How do I resolve this error so I can make this work with the pipe operator, without having to re-use the function code over and over again?

Thanks!

Comment: You need the data object

Comment: the %>% operator takes a data frame from the left and passes it to the first argument of the function on the right. State() doesn't accept a data frame, so you'll need to redefine Stata() with a data frame as the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adjusted the function to include an argument for the data frame, added the necessary packages within the function definitions and converted the inputs to characters rather than numbers. This could also be added to the function definition if required.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

State <- function(df, x, y){
  dplyr::mutate(
    df,
    Account = stringr::str_remove_all(Account, "-"),
    Account = case_when(
      startsWith(Account, y) ~ stringr::str_c(stringr::str_c("WC", x), "Policy #"),
      startsWith(Account, x) ~ stringr::str_c("WC", "Policy #")
    )
  )
}

df %>% State("32", "90")
```